# Can a subclass add parameters in a block in a parameter in an inherited method?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, methods, objective-c-blocks, overriding

## The situation

A superclass defines a method and a subclass redefines that method. The only difference is that the subclass adds a parameter in a block, which itself is a parameter of the method.

## An example

Imagine I have a class `Collection` and a descendant class `List`, which define—among other methods—an enumeration method in `NSArray`-style.

```
@interface Collection : NSObject
- (void)enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: (void (^)(id obj))block;
@end

@interface List : Collection
- (void)enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: (void (^)(id obj, int index))block;
@end
```

## The question

Does this work (on all platforms) and does it conform with standards?

I would imagine it would work since the parameter list in the superclass method isn’t affected, while users of the subclass method would be aware (optionally with some type-casting) of the extra parameter.

Comment: Since all methods in Objective-C are virtual hence this should work just fine.

Comment: @YasKuraishi The basic Objective-C part (ignoring the block parameters) would never complain, since blocks are `id`-equivalent. My question is: are the two different block types compatible (or covariant)?

Comment: I believe they are, like this should work just fine and print what ever will get passed from `List` method in `obj` param, since you are calling it on `Collection` variable therefore `index` param will get ignored: `Collection *coll = [List new]; [coll enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj) { NSLog(@"obj from List: %@", obj); }];`

Comment: @YasKuraishi If it works, it is only by coincidence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short;  no, don't do this.

Longer:

It'll work in most situations, but you'll have to strive to avoid compiler warnings.   Objective-C does not support co-variant or contra-variant declarations of methods (which was why `instancetype` was created).   Since the block types are different, the method argument types are different.

Nor can you assume that a functions, blocks or methods that take, say, `(a)`, (a,b)`, (a,b.c)`, `(a,b,c,d)`, etc... will be compatible at call site.  I.e. you can't say `fun(a,b,c,d)` where `fun` is actually `fun(a)` and be guaranteed that you'll get what you expect.